# Web requesting forwarding to another domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, networking

I have a site "MySite" setup in my IIS with the below HTTP bindings,

1. www.example.com:80
2. www.example.net:80
3. www.example.org:80

I need to temporarily redirect all users coming to `www.example.net` to  `www.example.com/product`.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: URL Rewrite rule?

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one

Answer (score 0):

Hi Siva Sankar Gurram,

You could use below url rewrite rule to redirect url www.example.net to  www.example.com/product by using below url rewrite rule in iis:

```
<rule name=".net to .com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/product" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Note: If you did not installed Url rewrite module first install it.